# encode object into cookie string for testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, user-agent, supertest

I'm using cookies to pass the session about the logged in user, and on the server I can set and get them fine:

```
res.cookie("foo", { bar: "baz" })

// later on
console.log(req.cookies.foo) // { bar: "baz" }
```

Now, I want to test it, and I need to set the cookie header, but I don't know how to convert an object, i.e. `{ bar: "baz" }`, to the header string the cookie evaluates to
[image]

What's the algorithm used here?

(I'm using supertest but it shouldn't matter IMO)

Answer (score 0):

In express by default the cookie is encoded, you need to pass the options to keep it as a string.

encode Function - A synchronous function used for cookie value encoding. Defaults to encodeURIComponent.

```
// Custom encoding
res.cookie("foo", { bar: "baz" }, {encode: String})
```

You can check [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) for more details.